# Black "grille" after stereographic projection+rotation

Tags: rotation, projection

When I do a stereographic projection and rotationX of omnidirectionnel image, I get this image:
[image]

My question why I get that "grille" in the image, it appears only when I add rotation

Answer (score 0):

This type of artifacts can happen when you transform pixels from your input to find their new location in the output. Due to precision, not all pixels in the target will be filled.

Try to do the reverse-projection instead. For each pixel in your final image find the corresponding coordinate in the source. You'll get non integer coordinates and will need to interpolate.